# bootstrap page transition mouse hover

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, css, mousehover

This is a java procect from codepen

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.nav li a[href^='#']").click(function(){
        $("html, body").stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

How can i make or replace code to desktop so that the page transition can happen with mousehover instead of click??i tried to replace .click(function() with .hover(function() but as i was afraid it didnt work.What could b the solution?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Write css code for that in `:hover`. The syntax is

```
(classname(.)or Id(#)followed by : symbol then hover)
```

The example code is as follows.

```
.(ul.nav li a:hover)
{
   //Remaing codes or funnctionlaities
}
```

Comment: i think its not working or im making a serious mistake..this is the procect i mntioned..https://codepen.io/PriscilaCunha/pen/ZGojLL again Thank you!!1